# How to disable ask to join page in jitsi?

Tags: android, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am using jitsi in my android studio app, but after creating meeting code it is redirecting to ask to join page, how can i disable that?

URL serverURL;

```
    try {
        serverURL = new URL("https://meet.jit.si/");
        JitsiMeetConferenceOptions defaultOptions =
                new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                        .setServerURL(serverURL)
                        .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                        .setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled",false)
                        .build();
        JitsiMeet.setDefaultConferenceOptions(defaultOptions);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    joinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                    .setRoom(secretCodeBox.getText().toString())
                    .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                    .build();

            JitsiMeetActivity.launch(DashboardActivity.this, options);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you found the answer? I am looking for exactly the same question.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118368/jitsi-meet-first-user-who-created-meeting-goes-to-lobby

Answer (score 0):

Use some random password, not an easy one like "1234", or "test123". What happening here is someone already using the same meeting password and obviously, you are not the moderator of the meeting so you need a password. use some complicated passwords which are not common.