# Jitsi meet first user who created meeting goes to lobby

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

in my flutter project ,issue is if user initially creates a meeting ,user is being redirected to lobby even if he is the one who first created the meeting.
and it say you will join the meeting as soon as someone accepts your request.

i tried using jitsi meet wrapper and also tried omni_jitsi_meet but both have same issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti3IL.png).

so if user first joined meeting then he should be going to meeting instead of lobby.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I also have this problem.

Comment: yes, if you don't provide server url then it will use jitsi default server https://meet.jit.si/ which require login to be moderator . now there are some community run servers https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/community/community-instances/ which doesn't require login to be moderator . just add serverurl in jitsi configuration with one of the community servers and it will run fine.

Comment: Thank You!! Now that problem is solved. I also have another problem. I have added jitsi SDK and created simple app and it's running well on Android Studio but not working after clicking on Join button on my real android devise after created apk file. You can get simple app source code in  https://github.com/altabmw01/jitismeetjoin

Answer (score 1):

solution :

if you don't provide server url then it will use jitsi default server meet.jit.si which require login to be moderator . now there are some community run servers jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/community/community-instances

which doesn't require login to be moderator . just add serverurl in jitsi configuration with one of the community servers and it will run fine

Answer (score 0):

solution :

for this problem there some community run servers that will provide server without moderator issue :

jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/community/community-instances

after going to this link select server according to your country or continent as given on the link page... paste that server in your app's server url.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).